# Karate-robot integration to java based selenium tests

Tags: karate

I have successfully added Karate-Robot to existing karate framework as karate-robot is available in maven repo. Aslo implemented in VSC for windows machine following https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide. Thanks for the great tool for Desktop app automation.

Background: I have selenium testng project as well as selenium cucumber project, And both projects are driven by testng framework (not Junit).
I am trying to use karate-robot desktop testing options in java class/methods directly so I can reuse it in selemium Java test classes directly instead of running karate-robot tests using karate DSL or through karate feature file. Is there any option in karate-robot implementation to do direct Java integration so I can call during selenium whenever necessary.

Objective is to replace winium windows desktop tests embedded in selenium tests by karate-robot.
Please let me know if there any options I can try with karate-robot to integrate directly with Java Selenium test classes.

Comment: I really don't understand this question. you should be able to integrate any java code into karate and java interop is explained in the documentation